# Find the todays's file in multiple folder using loop - LINUX

Tags: linux, bash, unix, find

I had a problem to list all the latest file in a selected folder. The situation is, the server had 15 folders starting name with 'backup'. So I need to a list all the latest file (including their name and size) in those folders using looping. So I came out with these code:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /
for i in ls -d backup*; do (`ls -tr | tail -1` $i) ; done
```

and it returned 17 rows of error messages which is:

```
./show_latest.sh: line 5: tmp: command not found
```

Need help from those who know about this.
TQVM

Problem solved here is the code:

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in ls -d backup*; do du -sh $(find /$i -mtime -1 -print ); done
```

Comment: Your code example only has four lines. The error is on line 5. Please show us the entire script `show_latest.sh` (or at least the fifth line!)

Comment: the rest is commented code. I didn't paste it here. Thanks for your respond

Comment: Problem **not** solved, and to convince yourself stick `echo $i;` between `do` and `du`.

Answer (score 0):

You need backticks around your `ls`:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /
for i in `ls -d backup*`; do (`ls -tr | tail -1` $i) ; done
```

Alternately, the following will give you all regular files in reverse time sorted order:

```
find . -type f -exec echo \'{}\' \;|xargs ls -tr
```

Comment: your find solution is ignoring the function of `ls -d backup*`, which is to select all directories which start with 'backup'. Try `find / -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "backup*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} find {} -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -tr`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even need the loop? Your second variant would look better as just

```
du -sh $(find /backup* -mtime -1)
```